# Grunt Speed: Directly Specifying Tasks vs Combining

Tags: gruntjs, abstraction, command-line-interface

With `Grunt`, when you are registering tasks, how much slower is it to use tasks you already registered, maybe with several subtasks of their own, versus using tasks straight from `initConfig`, or even writing the functions by hand in the registration? Here's an example:

How much slower would specifying `grunt minify` from the command line be here:

```
grunt.registerTask('minify', ['preprocessed', 'nonprocessed']);
gruntregisterTask('preprocessed', ['sass:convert', 'haml:convert']);
grunt.registerTask('nonprocessed', ['uglify', 'cssmin', 'htmlmin', 'phpmin']);
```

than if you created the `minify` task like this:

```
grunt.registerTask('minify', ['sass:convert', 'haml:convert', 'uglify', 'cssmin', 'htmlmin', 'phpmin']);
```

I have to believe there is at least some slowdown, as `Grunt` has to go through more steps to "see" the tasks at each level of abstraction, but I just want to know if it's something to worry about only with thousands of modules, tens of sub-tasks per task, etc. or if it'll affect smaller projects as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test this yourself by using [time-grunt](https://github.com/sindresorhus/time-grunt).

```
// Gruntfile.js
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    // require it at the top and pass in the grunt instance
    require('time-grunt')(grunt);

    grunt.initConfig();
}
```

Personally I've never noticed any speed decrease by specifying more aliases rather than less, and if there is slowdown it'll be in *milliseconds*. It'd be interesting to see a full test suite though.

Comment: Looks like there's some sort of problem with the server. Disappointing, but glad I probably finished my npm work for this project. Anyway, will test later.

Comment: I tested, and abstraction doesn't seem to increase the time much. In fact, tasks seem to fluctuate in how long they take anyway, sometimes by seconds. I assume this is because of CPU cycles, etc. Abstraction seems to change the time less than this inherent variability.